# @JvmField on properties for a generic/abstract class

Tags: kotlin

At the moment I have an [abstract class](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/Vec2t.kt#L15-L18):

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number> {    

    abstract var x: T    
    abstract var y: T
    ...
}
```

and many implementing ones, such as [this one](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/_2/Vec2.kt#L17):

```
data class Vec2(override var x: Float, override var y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>()
```

Now, my wish was to have the same access behaviour as Kotlin in Java, that is:

```
val f = v.x
```

or

```
v.x = f
```

but of course from Java the default was:

```
float f = v.getX();
```

or

```
v.setX(f);
```

I reduced somehow the "pressure" by writing specific [access funtions](https://github.com/elect86/glm/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/vec/Vec2t.kt#L20-L25):

```
fun x(x: T) {
    this.x = x
}
fun y(y: T) {
    this.y = y
}
```

so that I can "only":

```
float f = v.x();
```

or

```
v.x(f);
```

But still, I'd really love if I could have those as in Kotlin:

```
float f = v.x;
```

or

```
v.x = f;
```

The problem is that `@JvmField` is not allowed on `abstract` properties, but if I switch `Vec2t` to:

```
open class Vec2t<T : Number> {

    @JvmFiled open var x: T // error
```

> property must be initialized or abstract

```
    @JvmField open var x by Delegates.notNull<T>()
```

is not valid neither:

> @JvmField cannot be applied to delegate properties

if I tried to initialize it:

```
    @JvmField open var x = 0 as T
```

> @JvmField can only be applied to final properties

Is there a chance for me that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a `@JvmField` is accessed directly in Java, we can't initialize with anything tricky like a delegate, and can't mark it as `lateinit` either. This is also why it can't be backed by an abstract or open property; if you have `float x;` inside a class in Java, it's accessed directly, and you can't intercept reads/writes to it in any way, which all the above features would require.

The problem you're trying to solve is initializing them with valid values on creation. One thing you could do is mark them as nullable and intialize them as `null`, but I think that would go directly against the convenience you're looking for (and probably performance, since they'd now have to be boxed), I just thought I'd mention that it's possible.

All this to say is that you're basically stuck with one of your solutions, or if it suits your use case, I'd suggest intializing them from constructor parameters:

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number> constructor(_x: T, _y: T)  {

    @JvmField
    var x: T = _x

    @JvmField
    var y: T = _y

}

class Vec2(x: Float, y: Float) : Vec2t<Float>(x, y)
```

This way you have your values marked as `@JvmField`s and can access it directly from both languages, and they're intialized with a real value on creation.

**Update:**

Here is a shorter version (by [@mfulton26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255152/mfulton26)):

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number>(@JvmField var x: T, @JvmField var y: T)
```

Comment: Thanks zsmb, it looks perfect!

Comment: This `Vec2t` implementation can be simplified by placing the  `@JvmField` properties straight into the constructor: `abstract class Vec2t<T : Number>(@JvmField var x: T, @JvmField var y: T)`.

Comment: Oh right, I don't know why I didn't make that step, that's much neater. Got too fixed in to having them inside the class body I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

@JvmField instructs the Kotlin compiler not to generate getters/setters for this property and expose it as a field, so if it will be a field it will not possible to overwrite it.

For your case you need something like this:

```
abstract class Vec2t<T : Number> {
    @JvmField
    var x: T

    @JvmField
    var y: T
}
```

Comment: > Property must be initialized or abstract